# retrieve the user details like name address in Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, integration

hi I am using the latest Facebook SDK for native login and i have successfully login via native but I am not able to retrieve the user details like name address etc. i have used the below code. and  this line in my eclipse  is showing Deprecated.  Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback())

```
loginbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FacebookLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }); 
    public class FacebookLogin extends Activity{
    //private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;

    //private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebooklogin);

         Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

             // callback when session changes state
             @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
             public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
               if (session.isOpened()) {


                 // make request to the /me API
                 Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                   // callback after Graph API response with user object
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                     if (user != null) {
                      Log.i("USERName", ""+user.getName());
                      Log.i("Birthday", ""+user.getBirthday());
                      Log.i("LastName", ""+user.getLastName());
                      Log.i("FirstName", ""+user.getFirstName());


                        Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();

                     }
                   }
                 });



               }
             }
           });


    }





    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("onActivityResult", "called");

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);


        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {




           // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                     Log.i("USERName", ""+user.getName());
                      Log.i("Birthday", ""+user.getBirthday());
                     Log.i("LastName", ""+user.getLastName());
                     Log.i("FirstName", ""+user.getFirstName());

                        Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                        Log.i("USERName", ""+user.getName());
                }
              }
            });


          }else {
            finish();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i("onSaveInstanceState", "called");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I have done it. Check out this source code:
https://github.com/madhur/MapMyLocation/blob/develop/src/in/co/madhur/mapmylocation/activity/FBLogin.java

```
//Create the Request
Request meRequest=Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback()
                                {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                                        {
                                                if(response.getError()==null)
                                                {

                                                        appPreferences.setFBUserName(user.getName());
                                                }

                                        }
                                });
 //Execute the request
 meRequest.executeAsync();
```

Comment: in my eclipse is showing Deprecated. Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()) 
can you tell me why?

Comment: Its deprecated by facebook. Use meRequest.executeAsync() after creating the request object as I did.

Comment: i used this, but nothing happend
 Request meRequest=Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback() {
     
     @Override
     public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Log.i("USERName", ""+user.getName());
                       Log.i("Birthday", ""+user.getBirthday());
                       Log.i("LastName", ""+user.getLastName());
                       Log.i("FirstName", ""+user.getFirstName());
     }
    }); RequestAsyncTask asyncTask=meRequest.executeAsync();

Comment: and please could give me any sample like an activity having button an on click of button it will natively login and gives the user details or any help like that ?